# pass value to attribute based on received value

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, validationattribute

Im using C# 4.5 web api type project.

When receiving HttpPost requests from clients i want to validate the request fields.
The issue is that the input validation is depended on the input itself, or to be more specific, depends on provided enum.

Assuming I have the following class:

```
public class A 
{
     public myEnum Filter{set;get;}

     [myEnumCheckName(Filter)]
     public string Name {set;get;}

     [myEnumCheckEmail(Filter)]
     public string Email {set;get;}
}

public enum myEnum {ByName = 1, ByEmail = 2}
```

And also I wrote 2 validatorAttributes:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class myEnumCheckName : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly someNameValidator _validator = new someNameValidator();
    private readonly myEnum _filter;

    public myEnumCheckName(myEnum filter)
    {
        _filter = filter;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (_filter == myEnum.ByName)
            return _validator.IsValid(value);

        return true;
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class myEnumCheckEmail : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly someEmailValidator _validator = new someEmailValidator();
    private readonly myEnum _filter;

    public myEnumCheckEmail(myEnum filter)
    {
        _filter = filter;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (_filter == myEnum.ByEmail)
            return _validator.IsValid(value);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Problem is that when I try call `[myEnumCheckName(myEnum)` it says:

> Cannot access static property myEnum in static context.

Is there anyway to access the instance/current context field values?

Thanks.

**CLARIFICATION**

I want to validate the `Name` and `Email` properties, thats the general idea.
Now, I dont mind if `Name` would be null if the `Filter` value will be `ByEmail` and vice-versa.
this way, I dont have to write the same method that handles the request twice.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Your first code block is full of syntax errors. Also, research the _actual_ error you receive. The problem is that you have a member name that is equal to the enum name. Use the enum's full namespace in the attribute.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to check if the `Name` field is not empty, but only when the provided enum value equals to `ByName`? Please clarify. Also, as a side note, your attribute declarations are missing a closing square bracket, so CodeCaster is right.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma you understood it well. and CodeCaster is right when i missed 2 brackets but it is not a reason to downvote a question and claim that only because of those 2 brackets my entire question is not well written. Also, added clarification in question

Comment: Class `A` also has an incomplete property declaration `public myEnum {set;get;}`. Anyway no, you cannot use variables in attributes, they must be compile-time constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve this kind of validation logic using the built-in Validation framework from `ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`. If you want to automatically validate your class properties based on other properties values, then you should switch to a different validation framework that has such feature.

I suggest you to look into [`FluentValidation`](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation), and create custom validators for your classes that can easily handle complex situations like the one you described. You could, for example, create a validator for your `A` class similar to the following one:

```
public class AValidator: AbstractValidator<A>
{
    public AValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(a => a.Name)
            .NotEmpty()
            .When(c => c.Filter == myEnum.ByName);

        RuleFor(a => a.Email)
            .NotEmpty()
            .When(c => c.Filter == myEnum.ByEmail);
    }
}
```

To know more on how to integrate `FluentValidation` into Web Api you may refer to the following tutorial (you may ignore the Ninject part if you do not want to provide validators through a dependency injection framework):
http://sergeyakopov.com/restful-validation-with-asp-net-web-api-and-fluentvalidation/